# Why the if loop is iterating twice before asking for next input?

Tags: c, for-loop

I am writing a C program which would generate a random character each time and would compare it with the user entered character. User is provided five chances for guessing the answer.

I have also used `scanf("%c",&ans)` instead of `getchar` but it also not working.

```c
    srand(time(NULL));
    char randomChar=rand()%('z'-'a'+1)+'a';
    printf("%c",randomChar);
    for(i=1;i<=5;++i){
        printf("Enter your guess:\n");
        ans=getchar();
        if(ans==randomChar){
            printf("Whoa!!Your guess was correct\n");
            break;
        }
        else{
            p=p-1;
            printf("Wrong guess,you have %d more chances\n",p);
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Output:

```c
aEnter your guess:
p
Wrong guess,you have 4 more chances
Enter your guess:
Wrong guess,you have 3 more chances
Enter your guess:
```

Comment: Substitute ans=getchar(); for scanf( " %c", &ans ); getchar reads also white spaces.

Comment: I don't see a definition for `p`. Where is that variable set or declared?

Comment: When you print the random character, it's not very difficult to "guess" it, is it? :D

Comment: @shashwat p is declared equal to 5 in some upper part of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute

`ans=getchar();`

for

`scanf( " %c", &ans );`

(pay attention to the blank before the format specifier `%c`.)

`getchar` reads also white spaces (for example the new line character stored in the buffer after pressing Enter).

Comment: Why is it necessary to use a space before %c? Without a space before %c it is not working!